# D3.js loading spinner not functioning properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, d3.js, safari

I would like to use loading spinner in my JavaScript code during the loading of a new web page. The code is copied (and not modified) from http://bl.ocks.org/Mattwoelk/6132258. In other words, when I click on a node until new page displays I would like this spinner to spin.

My code is as follows and is working just fine in Firefox and Chrome. It just does not work in Safari. If I comment out the "window.location" line this works also in Safari, but then it (of course) does not redirect to a new page.

```
node.on("dblclick", function(d){
    force.stop();
    var myLoader = loader({width: graphSize[0], height: graphSize[1], container: "#svgGraph", id: "loader"});
    myLoader();
    window.location = urlBase + d.article_id;
});
```

So how can I make this work in Safari?

NOTE: app is deployed here http://butler.fri.uni-lj.si/articles/pubmed/21223996. After clicking on one of the node the spinner should spin until new page is displayed.

Comment: Have a try with `document.location`.

Comment: @MarcoCI Does not work either :-(

Comment: I see it working for a sec, but instead of replacing the page while spinning it freeze and load a brand new page.

Comment: @MarcoCI yes, that's the problem. If you try in Firefox you can see how it should work.